# Чтение бинарного файла в массив байт в micropython

Tags: micropython

Всем привет!
При чтении бинарного файла в массив micropython автоматически подменяет перенос строки вида "`\r\n`" на "`\r`".

Вот минимальный код, проверяю на esp32:

```
with open("test_file.bin", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    print(len(data))
```

Содержимое файла:

```
0x48 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F 0x0D 0x0A 0x57 0x6F 0x72 0x6C 0x64 0x21
```

а в консоль выводится

```
0x48 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F 0x0D 0x57 0x6F 0x72 0x6C 0x64 0x21
```

то есть он просто отбрасывает байт `0x0A`.

Параметр newline для функции открытия файла не работает в micropython, выдаёт ошибку

```
extra keyword arguments given
```

Существует ли способ в micropython прочитать файл в массив байт как есть, без каких бы то ни было модификаций?

Comment: В бинарном режиме файл всегда читается "как есть" вообще-то. На то он и бинарный режим.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, micropython читает файл корректно, просто uPyCraft изменил файл при записи